# Historic list of scripts that have been run on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, script, history

I expect that this is wishful thinking but my work (Linux) server contains a lot of scripts not particularly well organised. I am new to Linux, would there be a historical list of scripts that have recently ran?

Comment: Run by a user or run by the system? And if by a user, is the account shared by the server administrators?

Answer (score 0):

The `history` command will list commands run by a given user which should include any scripts that have been run.

Comment: in `bash` the `history` command is a shell built-in command (see `man bash` or `help history` while running `bash`).  the environment variable `HISTFILE`, if set, specifies the history list location; if not set a builtin default is used (`$HOME/.bash_history` on my system).  `history` itself won't show you the history of other users, but you could inspect their `/home/otheruser/.bash_history` file if it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why hardillb got voted down, he's correct.  Check the .bash_history, or history command.  If you have root, check other users history.  You can use `last` to see which user has logged in, when, and check that user's history.  It won't help with system cron commands.

To his response I will add:

1. Use `find ./ type -f -atime -7 -iname "*.sh"` (or *.pl, or any other script extensions you can think of.).  This will tell you files that were accessed in the last **7** days according to the FS access time value.  It won't work if the filesystem has been mounted with noatime.
2. Check /var/log/cronlog or syslog if it isn't logging cron events.
3. If you add `-executable` to that find command above, instead of looking for "*.sh" or "*.pl", then it should find files with an executable bit that have been accessed in 7 days.  Not all scripts are executable, so the -iname option is useful too.

The list provided by "find" won't be access time sorted, but you can pseudo-accomplish it by testing with -1, then -2, then -3 ... -7 days, at least they'll be grouped by day.

HTH.